# Iframe. Изменить размер содержимого

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Есть **iframe**. Он хватает сайт с онлайн игрой.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы:

1. он хватал только игру (более менее есть решения, но лучше
   подсказать))
2. изменял размер самой игры

То есть игра там во весь экран, а нужно чтобы была она же, только меньше размером. Чтобы скролить не надо было.

Comment: И такой ещё вопросик. Как войти в свою учётку, через приложение) Сюда то я вошёл через ВК... Эх... Надо было через Гугл заходить)

Comment: jquery или angularjs используется на сайте?